# Is it okay to say in a Masters thesis conclusion that the used methodology is not worth exploring?

Tags: masters

Is it acceptable to say in a thesis that based on how this methodology was implemented, it is not worth additional exploration because it is just too complex for the accuracy that it provides?

Thanks

Comment: Acceptable to who?

Comment: You need to ask your thesis advisor this question.

Comment: Just *saying* it probably isn't a good idea.  Making a rational, evidence-based case for it might be OK.

Comment: I tried to simulate an experiment and validate results using a computer software. 

@BryanKrause just as an overall conclusion in the future outlook. I am just advising based on my results that it is not worth pursuing and providing some ideas on how to do it.

Comment: @DanielHatton Yes that's right. I will be providing evidence. I was just wondering whether if it is acceptable it make it obvious that this is a negative result or should I just focus on the positives only.

Comment: @Rayana My question was *to who* is it acceptable: from whose perspective are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are two aspects here. The first is that the methodology is (very) complex relative to the accuracy. The second is that it isn't worth pursuing/using in the future.

The former is probably fact based but the latter is pure opinion. Perhaps others would have a different opinion and/or could use the methodology as a stepping stone to something "better".

You might consider leaving out the opinion part or clearly marking it as your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Negative conclusions are important, but they are undervalued, and not as often published as is warranted. Thus, in principle, a thesis that shows that a certain way does not seem to be promising, should be just as valuable as one that shows the opposite.

In a M.S. thesis, you want to only state things that you can support scientifically, but in the conclusion, you are free to voice your personal opinion, as long as it is based on your work. Your readers are free to disagree, whereas they should not have this opportunity with your experiments and calculations (because if they could do so, then your work is sloppy or contains errors).

If I understand you correctly, your implementation of a certain methodology is cumbersome and does not provide additional accuracy that would make it worth while. That is a good result, because it means that others would either come up with an idea to implement the methodology better than you or find some other aspect of it that can be improved. At a defense, you might even be asked what advice you would like to give to someone else.